# Get NSArray/NSDictionary for Nested JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have this JSON :

```
      {
        "_id" : "class_1",
        "schedule" : [ 
        {
            "date" : "1-1-2014",
            "subjects" : [ 
                {
                    "time_range" : "08:00-10:00",
                    "subject" : "Sports"
                }, 
                {
                    "time_range" : "10:00-12:00",
                    "subject" : "History"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "2-1-2014",
            "subjects" : [ 
                {
                    "time_range" : "08:00-10:00",
                    "subject" : "Physics"
                }, 
                {
                    "time_range" : "10:00-12:00",
                    "subject" : "Chemistry"
                },
                {
                    "time_range" : "10:00-12:00",
                    "subject" : "Biology"
                }

            ]
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "3-1-2014",
            "subjects" : [ 
                {
                    "time_range" : "08:00-10:00",
                    "subject" : "English"
                }, 
                {
                    "time_range" : "10:00-12:00",
                    "subject" : "Maths"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "date" : "4-1-2014",
            "subjects" : [ 
                {
                    "time_range" : "08:00-10:00",
                    "subject" : "Spanish"
                }, 
                {
                    "time_range" : "10:00-12:00",
                    "subject" : "Choreography"
                }, 
                {
                    "time_range" : "12:00-14:00",
                    "subject" : "Music"
                }, 
                {
                    "time_range" : "14:00-16:00",
                    "subject" : "Sports"
                }, 
                {
                    "time_range" : "16:30-18:30",
                    "subject" : "Religion"
                }
            ]
        }           
    ]
    }
```

What I would like to do is get an NSArray/NSMutableArray or NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary` with the subjects for a GIVEN date. So for example if I type in the date 4-1-2014, I would like to get an array or dictionary with the 5 subjects that are contained in that date.

What I would like to do is get an NSArray/NSMutableArray or NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary with the subjects for a GIVEN date. So for example if I type in the date 1-1-2014, I would like to get an array or dictionary with the 2 subjects that are contained in that date.

This is what I have tried:

```
//NSDICTIONARY CONTAINING CLASS DATA FOR CLASS ID 
NSDictionary *classData = 
 [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

//NSMUTABLEDICTIONARY CONTAINING SCHEDULE DATA FOR CLASS ID
NSMutableArray *scheduleDatabyClassID = [classData objectForKey:@"schedule"];

//NSMUTABLEARRAY CONTAINING SCHEDULE SUBJECTS OF CLASS ID
NSMutableArray *subjectsDatabyDate =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;


    for (NSMutableDictionary *subjectsData in scheduleDatabyClassID ){
    NSString *subjectsData_temp = [subjectsData  objectForKey:@"subjects"];
    NSString *schedule_date = [subjectsData  objectForKey:@"date"];        
    NSString *check = @"25-11-2013";
    if ([schedule_date isEqualToString:check]) {            
       [subjectsDatabyDate addObject:subjectsData_temp];
    }        

}
```

Below is what I would like to get, but WITHOUT MANUALLY setting the index to 0. I want subjectsDataByDate : for the value (1-1-2014) for example.

```
NSLog(@"subjectsDatabyDate \n %@ ", [subjectsDatabyDate objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) being one.

Comment: Parse the JSON into dictionaries/arrays and then access what you want.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Show us what you've tried, why it didn’t meet your needs and any error messages. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers,  and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hint: `[subjectsData  objectForKey:@"subjects"];` is an `NSArray`, not an `NSString`.

Comment: It helps to understand an NSLog dump.  In the `description` format used to log arrays and dictionaries, the `()` characters always "bracket" NS(Mutable)Arrays and the `{}` characters always "bracket" NS(Mutable)Dictionarys.  Sometimes the eye ignores the outermost `()` characters especially, so you have to train yourself to look carefully.  JSON is always "deserialized" into a "nest" of dictionaries and arrays, and if you understand the resulting structure it's quite easy to "navigate" to where you want to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick. As I mentioned, I needed a function that returns me an NSArray with containing the GIVEN date:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date==%@",@"1-1-2014"]; 
NSArray *result_wanted = [scheduleDatabyClassID filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"THE RESULT \n %@ ", result_wanted);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do this for many different dates, and repeatedly, I would proceed somehow different.

NSDictionary is a class for key-value pairs. Your whole JSON data is actually a dictionary with keys "_id" and "schedule", and "schedule" has an array value. But looking at the data, a dictionary would have been much more appropriate, with for example "1-1-2014" as key and the rest as data. So you could turn the whole array into a dictionary, similar to your own code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *subjectsDatabyDate =[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] ;

for (NSDictionary *subjectsData in scheduleDatabyClassID )
{
    NSString *schedule_date = [subjectsData  objectForKey:@"date"];   
    subjectsDatabyDate [schedule_date] = subjectsData;     
}
```

Now you can access *any* date very quickly:

```
NSDictionary* result_wanted = subjectsDatabyDate [@"1-1-2014"];
```

The difference is that access to an NSDictionary uses a hash table that will go *directly* to the item that you want, while the "filteredArray" has to iterate through the whole array, every time you look for a date.